# Android Navigation Bar height React-Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the Android Bottom bar working (the bar where you have the back button) height with RN. I did the following:

```
Dimensions.get('window').height
```

I get the height with this bar! Since it can or cannot be there and can be bigger or larger depending on the settings, this is a big issue for me.

Comment: [Difference between 'window' and 'screen' in the Dimensions API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44979327/4360116)

Comment: Probably https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-detect-navbar-android is what you are looking for

Answer (score 52):

- In iOS devices, `screenHeight === windowHeight`;
- In Android devices with bottom navigator bar, `screen height === windowHeight + statusBarHeight + bottomNavigatorBarHeight` ;
- In Android devices without bottom navigator bar, `bottomNavigatorBarHeight` is zero.

```
import {Dimensions, StatusBar} from 'react-native'; 

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('screen').height; // device height
const STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = StatusBar.currentHeight || 24; 
const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

[image]

Comment: I've found that it seems to vary a little on Android. Newer versions of Android this seems correct, older versions `windowHeight` seemed to be including the `statusBarHeight` too - which is quite confusing.

Comment: Hi, should you mind sharing more details? Which version and device model do you use?

Comment: Using a basic formula to set a minimum CSS height `Dimensions.get('window').height - HEADER_HEIGHT - FOOTER_HEIGHT` (where HEADER_HEIGHT = 400, FOOTER_HEIGHT = 200) this is 100% of the screen height on a newer device (e.g. Nokia 8.1 and a OnePlus6T phone). On all the emulators I'm using and a Galaxy S6 I need to subtract the `statusBarHeight` as well 
for it to be exactly 100%

Comment: FYI, `statusBarHeight` does not exist on react-native's `StatusBar` anymore, you need to use `StatusBar.currentHeight`.

Answer (score 11):

I use sheet below to do that:

```
// RN version:0.57.0
let deviceH = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
// the value returned does not include the bottom navigation bar, I am not sure why yours does.
let windowH = Dimensions.get('window').height;
let bottomNavBarH = deviceH - windowH;
```

Comment: I think the problem with this method is it will also account for the status bar height. For example i have gesture navigation turned on so no navbar to display but it is still returning a height of 25 for the status bar.

Comment: You can subtract the StatusBar.currentHeight from it then, which seems to match perfectly for a Pixel 7 Pro:
`const bottomNavBarH = deviceH - windowH - (StatusBar.currentHeight ?? 0);`

Answer (score 9):

```
import { Dimensions , StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const navbarHeight = screenHeight - windowHeight + StatusBar.currentHeight;
```

Comment: for me this reports the same height with the bar visible as when it's hidden?

Answer (score 3):

There is a new library which works like a charm

https://github.com/ConnectyCube/react-native-android-navbar-height

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { getNavigationBarHeight } from "react-native-android-navbar-height";

// ...

const scale = Dimensions.get('screen').scale;
const navigationBarHeight = await getNavigationBarHeight();
const result = navigationBarHeight / scale;
```

Comment: Yo, publish it to npm.

Answer (score 2):

first we need import

```
import { Dimensions , StatusBar } from 'react-native';
```

**WindowHeight** = `Dimensions.get('window').height` .
**ScreenHeight** = `Dimensions.get('screen').height` .
**StatusBarHeight** = StatusBar.currentHeight

**WindowHeight** = *ScreenHeight* - *NavigationBarHeight*

when we want to implement float button in the bottom of our page set **WindowHeight** for that's height and set `bottom : StatusBar.currentHeight` for child element .

when we *don't have* **NavigationBar** , 
**WindowHeight** = *ScreenHeight*

Answer (score 1):

First as mentioned in other answers using react native Dimensions API  in **Android** the window height= screen height - (status bar height + navigation bar height)

After few hours of investigations I found that in some **Android** devices Dimensions API gives a wrong window height number.

the solution for is using [react-native-extra-dimensions-android][1]

[1]: https://github.com/Sunhat/react-native-extra-dimensions-android it give you the following information:

REAL_WINDOW_HEIGHT - Actual height of screen including system decor elements
REAL_WINDOW_WIDTH - Actual width of screen including system decor elements
STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT - Height of the status bar
SOFT_MENU_BAR_HEIGHT - Height of the soft menu bar (supported on most new Android devices)

then you can calculate window height: REAL_WINDOW_HEIGHT -(STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT + SOFT_MENU_BAR_HEIGHT)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const navbarHeight = screenHeight - windowHeight + StatusBar.currentHeight;
```

In the landscape case, this is wrong and will get a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

**Dimensions.get('screen').height - Dimensions.get('window').height - StatusBar.currentHeight** will give you the bottom navigation bar height.

In older Android phones, sometimes the status bar height is included in Dimensions.get('window').height as well as mentioned by [@Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21061/ian) above.

To tackle it, we need to **add back the StatusBar.currentHeight** in the case of such devices.

I was unable to find any Device property that can inform us of this behavior of Dimensions.get('window').height, so i solved it with this approach:

1. Create a View with style={{flex:1}} . It should be the only parent View in the screen, so that it covers the whole screen.
2. Measure the height of this view using onLayout.
3. Compare it with Dimensions.get('window').height
4. The devices with a difference greater than 1 are the one ,we were finding.

**Working Code:** ***(Remember to call the MyComponent inside a empty Screen.)***

```js
import { SCREENS_HEIGHT } from 'constants/constants';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StatusBar, Text, View } from 'react-native';
const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [statusBarIncludedInWindowHeight, setStatusBarIncludedInWindowHeight] = useState(false);
  const navbarHeight =
    Dimensions.get('screen').height -
    Dimensions.get('window').height -
    (StatusBar.currentHeight || 0);
  return (
    <View
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      onLayout={({
        nativeEvent: {
          layout: { height },
        },
      }) => {
        setStatusBarIncludedInWindowHeight(Math.abs(height - SCREENS_HEIGHT) > 1);
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>
        Navbar Height is :{' '}
        {navbarHeight + (statusBarIncludedInWindowHeight ? StatusBar.currentHeight || 0 : 0)}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score -3):

If you're referring to the status bar on top.

According to [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#constants) you can use

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
```

then in your code

```
StatusBar.currentHeight
```

UPDATE

You can get this using this module [react-native-extra-dimensions-android](https://github.com/Sunhat/react-native-extra-dimensions-android)

To detect if the soft android nav is present, you can use this module [react-native-detect-navbar-android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-detect-navbar-android).

Comment: The OP is talking about the on-screen navigation bar with the back and home buttons not the status bar.

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a way to know if it il present or not ?

Comment: yes you can use this  [react-native-detect-navbar-android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-detect-navbar-android)

Comment: It seems to do the trick. I didn't have the time to fully check it out yet, especially when there is no bar present. For now it will do ! Thanks a lot !