# Not getting accurate screen height and width with Dimensions in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use `Dimensions` to get device screen height and width.

Below is my code:

```
return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaView}>
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                
            </View>
            <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
                <Text>Hello</Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

And this the style which I am using:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
    mainContainer: {
        height: (Dimensions.get('window').height / 100) * 80,
        backgroundColor: "blue",
    },
    footerContainer: {
        top:  (Dimensions.get('window').height / 100) * 80,
        height: (Dimensions.get('window').height / 100) * 20,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 100 * 100,
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        position: "absolute",
        justifyContent: "flex-end"
    }
});
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

As you can see I am not able to see the `<Text>Hello</Text>`.
I am doing basic mathematics with `(Dimensions.get('window').height / 100) * 80`. I am taking total height of the screen, dividing it by hundred and then multiplying the result with the required number: this will give me the percentage height of the screen. I don't want to use flex. I want to go forward with the process which I am following. I just want to know why my `Hello` text is going below the screen.

It works on some device but not on another. It works in Pixel4 emulator, but not on Pixel3 emulator. If my dimensions calculation is right, then why is it not working on all the devices??

Comment: Its may be due to the bottom buttons on some android devices. or you can remove justifyContent: "flex-end" to show on all devices

Comment: @pankajchaturvedi I have design in which I have to give `justiyContent: "flex-end"`. Also I am using `SafeAreaView`, so it should work? right??

Comment: You are using SafeAreaView but you are forcing it to have 20% of the screen height. It can go out of the screen. @pankajchaturvedi is right, on some devices, bottom buttons is also added to the screen height. I don't understand why you don't want to use flex but if you are insisting on using dimensions api, you can look up to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60561393/5793132

Comment: How does your safeAreaView styles look like?

Answer (score 0):

"why is it not working on all the devices??" - this is because **Dimensions.get('...').height** is currently buggy in Android [see this issue.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23693)

To get **WINDOW_HEIGHT_NO_STATUS_BAR** and **STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT** (so window full height = WINDOW_HEIGHT_NO_STATUS_BAR + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT)

I used this code:

```
import { getStatusBarHeight } from 'react-native-status-bar-height'
import { initialWindowMetrics } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'

export const STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = getStatusBarHeight()

export const WINDOW_HEIGHT_NO_STATUS_BAR = Platform.OS !== 'ios' && Dimensions.get('screen').height !== Dimensions.get('window').height && STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT > 24 
? Dimensions.get('screen').height - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT 
: STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT > 24 
  ? Dimensions.get('window').height - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT 
  : Dimensions.get('window').height + initialWindowMetrics.insets.bottom === Dimensions.get('screen').height 
    ? Dimensions.get('window').height - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT 
    : Dimensions.get('window').height
```