# React-Native : How to get the complete height of the device when 'Full Screen Mode' is enabled?

Tags: react-native, android-fullscreen

I am taking the `Window` height by using `Dimensions.get('window').height` and rendering content over screen. But when `Full Screen Mode` is enabled hardware buttons are hidden which results to an extra space over the screen. But still `Dimensions.get('window').height` is giving as same height as previous(when `Full Screen Mode` was disabled). Eventually screen ends up with an extra space.

Is there any way in `react-native` to render the content according to `Full Screen Mode`?

And, How to get the complete height of the device when 'Full Screen Mode' is enabled?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a difference between `window` and `screen` in the Dimensions api.

For the most part
`Dimensions.get('window').height !== Dimensions.get('screen').height`

This SO answer does a great job of describing the difference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44979327/5508175

## tl;dr

- `window`: reports width/height without the soft menu bar
- `screen`: reports entire screen's width/height

I think you want to use `screen` rather than `window`

Alternatively in your styling you can try something like

`{ top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }`

and it should cover the whole screen

Comment: is there any way to know wether soft menu bar is enabled or not?

Comment: Not currently in react-native, you would have to implement your own native module. That exposes the `getSystemUiVisibility` functionality allowing you to know whether or not the `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` had been set or not. If it hasn't been set then the soft menu bar would be visible. The problem with the `Dimensions` api is that calling it on `window` will calculate the height of screen minus the height of the soft menu bar.

Comment: The following dependencies may be of some help https://github.com/Anthonyzou/react-native-full-screen https://github.com/Sunhat/react-native-extra-dimensions-android

Comment: Awesome!. This is what I am looking for. May I know the file name that contains `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`?  And Can I access this prop by using bridge between `native` and `react-native`?